# Hyper-V How to define "auto revert" to a snapshot after each reboot

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, snapshot

I'm using the built-in Hyper-V that comes with Windows Server 2012 R2
and I'm looking for the option that lets me to set "auto revert" (or "auto apply")
to a specific snapshot after the machine is rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. Simple like that.

This is not a functionality a enterprise level production hypervisor will likely support because it is not needed in an enterprise production environment.

It is mostly a feature used for development machines.

You could possibly write a script for that to run on start, but you can not do that without some programming. It is not a standard feature.

Comment: Strange, because this is a simple feature in VMware: VM Settings -> change the disk to Independent -> Non-persistent.

Comment: It may be like that in VmWare but hey, this is a question about Virtualization and I ahve never seen that being used in a production environment. I ahve seen somene loose a LOT of money because of a feature like that though. Actully shutting down a company due to the loss of that feature. So no, Hyper-V does not support it, regardless how easy you think that is in VmWare.